# GithubActions - How to send messges to Microsoft teams looping through an array returned by listForRepo

Tags: for-loop, github, github-actions, webhooks

The below returns an array listOfRepo

const listOfRepo = await github.rest.issues.listForRepo({
owner,
repo,
labels: openLabel,
state: "open",
});

Now I need to loop through each issue of listOfRepo and send a message each time to Microsoft Teams

```
        for (const issue of listOfRepo.data) {
          - name: sending a Microsoft Teams message
            **uses: neonidian/teams-notify-build-status@v3**
            with:
              webhookUrl: ${{ secrets.TEAMS_INCOMING_WEBHOOK_URL }}
              message: xxx
        }
```

The above code is failing as I cannot use the Github actions workflow in a for loop.

How do I send a message to MS Teams for each issue in a loop.